# JPA + Hibernate mapping java.util.Set in one Entity to another Entity java.util.Map

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a problem with JPA + Hibernate mapping in my project(I'm a total newbie to hibernate and jpa so please, be patient :) ).

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "yeasts")
public class Yeast {

...
private Set<BeerRecipe> recipes;
...

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "recipe_yeasts"
        ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "yst_id", referencedColumnName = "yst_id")
        ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "brp_id", referencedColumnName = "brp_id"))
public Set<BeerRecipe> getRecipes() {
    return recipes;
}

public void setRecipes(Set<BeerRecipe> recipes) {
    this.recipes = recipes;
}
}
```

and the second one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "beer_recipes")
public class BeerRecipe {

...
private Map<Yeast,Double> yeasts;
...
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name = "recipe_yeasts"
        ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "yst_id", referencedColumnName = "yst_id")
        ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "brp_id", referencedColumnName = "brp_id"))
public Map<Yeast, Double> getYeasts() {
    return yeasts;
}

public void setYeasts(Map<Yeast, Double> yeasts) {
    this.yeasts = yeasts;
}

...
}
```

I'm stuck here, because I can't find a solution to my problem. I need my BeerRecipe objects to store a Map< Yeast,Double> (double stands for amount of yeasts used in beer recipe), and Yeast objects to store Set< BeerRecipe>(many to many relationship - X beer recipes using the same yeasts and X yeasts being used in the same recipe)

Right now I'm getting an exception:

```
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: 
my.project.db_model.BeerRecipe.yeasts[java.lang.Double]
```

Comment: You cannot have `@ElementCollection` with `@ManyToMany`. JPA docs tell you what you can and cant have. Also a Set and a Map are incompatible for two ends of a relation

Answer (score 0):

An example solution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "yeasts")
public class Yeast {

    @Id
    private int yst_id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="yeasts")
    private Set<BeerRecipe> recipes;

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "beer_recipes")
public class BeerRecipe {

    @Id
    private int brd_id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "recipe_yeasts", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "brd_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "yst_id", referencedColumnName = "yst_id") //refers to Yeast
    @Column(name = "amount") //refers to Double
    private Map<Yeast, Double> yeasts;

    ...
}
```

With such approach you preserve bidirectional relationship between beer_recipes and yeast. The map stands for recipe_yeasts join table in between.